# Android Studio keeps giving me nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android

Hi i am doing a project that is due wednesday and i have spent over 13 hours trying to get Android studio working again, first their was a problem with the gradle and now i keep getting a nullpointerexception even though it same code that was working before. here is the code, please help? because i am stuck and could be doing my project rather that trying to solve android studios problems. by the way there are no errors within the code it says but here is the code.

```
            package ie.wit.fitnessmadeeasy;


            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.EditText;
            import android.widget.TextView;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            public class LogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            DataBaseHelper helper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

            EditText uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
            String unstr = uname.getText().toString();
           EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
           String passstr = pass.getText().toString();

              @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_log);


            TextView registerLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.regHere);          //register link creates a link between the two pages

          registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LogActivity.this,   RegisterActivity.class);
            LogActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);  //what this does it creates an intent that opens the registeravtivity then it tells the current activity to perform the intent and open the register page
        }
    });
}


// Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);




public void onLogClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.login) {


        String Password = helper.searchPassstr(unstr);
        Log.v("pass", passstr);
        Log.v("pass", Password);



        if (passstr.equals(Password)) {

            Intent i = new Intent(LogActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("username", unstr);

            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Toast temp = Toast.makeText(LogActivity.this, "Username and Password don't Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            temp.show();
        }
    }

}
```

}

```
   package ie.wit.fitnessmadeeasy;


   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   //import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.Toast;



    public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DataBaseHelper helper = new DataBaseHelper(this);


    final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);
    final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    final EditText password1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
   final EditText password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);

   String namestr = name.getText().toString();
   String usernamestr = username.getText().toString();
   String password1str = password1.getText().toString();
   String password2str = password2.getText().toString();

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);



   // final EditText password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);


    name.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if(name.getText().length()==0){

                name.setError("Fill Out");
            }
           else if(username.getText().length()==0){

                username.setError("Fill Out");
            }


        }

    });


}


public void onRegClick(View v)
{

    if(v.getId() == R.id.confirm)
    {
       //  EditText age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_age); //age is a final variable and is only assigned to activity_register as a view


       // EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);
       // EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
       // EditText password1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
       // EditText password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password2);




        if(namestr.equals("")){
            Toast pass = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Enter Name!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            pass.show();
        }
        if(usernamestr.equals("")){
            Toast pass = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Enter Username!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            pass.show();
        }
        if(password1str.equals("")){
            Toast pass = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Enter Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            pass.show();
        }
        if(!password1str.equals(password2str))
        {
            //popup message
            Toast pass = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Passwords don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            pass.show();
        }
         else{

            // String namestr = name.getText().toString();
            //insert details
            RegRequest reg = new RegRequest();
            reg.setEt_name(namestr);
            reg.setEt_username(usernamestr);
            reg.setEt_password(password1str);
           // r.setEt_age(agestr);

            Toast success = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            success.show();


            Intent i = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LogActivity.class);

            startActivity(i);

            helper.insertUser(reg);
        }




    }
}
```

}

```
            package ie.wit.fitnessmadeeasy;
           public class RegRequest{
           String et_name , et_username, et_password;
```

// int et_age;

```
          public void setEt_name(String et_name)
           {
          this.et_name = et_name;
           }

          public String getEt_name()
          {
         return this.et_name;
           }

public void setEt_username(String et_username)
{
    this.et_username = et_username;
}

public String getEt_username()
{
    return this.et_username;
}

public void setEt_password(String et_password)
{
    this.et_password = et_password;
}

public String getEt_password()
{
    return this.et_password;
}
```

}

```
       at ie.wit.fitnessmadeeasy.LogActivity.<init>(LogActivity.java:17)
```

Comment: So, where is the code?!?

Comment: Here is the code! where ?

Comment: A stack trace would also be useful.

Comment: it says it's starting with the EditText

Comment: I am pretty sure that ``uname`` or ``pass`` is simply null. Check the names of the resources.

if not, post the stack trace, we can not guess where it happens.

Comment: ok one second i put it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LogActivity.java

Only declare the fields like the following:

```
EditText uname, pass;
String unstr, passstr;
```

Initialize in `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_log);

     uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
     unstr = uname.getText().toString();
     pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
     passstr = pass.getText().toString();

}
```

And RegisterActivity.java

```
DataBaseHelper helper ;

EditText name, username,password1,password2;
String namestr,usernamestr,password1str,password2str;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    helper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    password1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);

   namestr = name.getText().toString();
   usernamestr = username.getText().toString();
   password1str = password1.getText().toString();
   password2str = password2.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: im going to try that now

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: ie.wit.fitnessmadeeasy, PID: 3298
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ie.wit.fitnessmadeeasy/ie.wit.fitnessmadeeasy.LogActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference same problem

Comment: i'm running it now to see will it work

Comment: I am still getting the same error,

Comment: trying that now but it worked perfect for me yesterday and the application crashed and i have had a problem ever since

Comment: it's starting up now but wont let me go to the register page now through the intent

Comment: now giving the same error on the register page

Comment: make sure you initialize data member of RegisterActivity.java in onCreate() method